# Battery or power issues in Ubuntu

Tags: power-management, battery

I have installed Ubuntu in my dell G3 in the sense of dual boot mode.when I was using Windows, it takes me nearly 5 hr to drain my battery. But when it comes to Ubuntu,literally the battery is getting down in just 1h 30 min to 2 h. I don't know why Ubuntu is consuming more battery compared to Windows.
Does anyone has any idea about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu does not automatically enable some of the power saving features that you might want.  A good first step would be to enable Tlp:

```
sudo apt install tlp
```

you can check the default settings, whoch are stored at "/etc/default/tlp" and edit them as desired, then either restart your computer or issue the command

```
sudo tlp start
```

You may also want the packages `thermald`, `lm-sensors` and `psensor`